# Does alloca() return memory if an exception is thrown?

Tags: c++, c, exception, alloca

I'm maintaining a legacy C++ application that seems to have a slow memory leak. I've managed to "fix" the memory leak by ensuring that the current configuration no longer throws any exceptions and I can also trigger the leak and scale it by configuring it to result in many exceptions.

All the memory that is allocated is done using alloca() rather than malloc(). The explanation I've been given for this is that it's because alloca() works like the java garbage collector and automatically frees the memory when it exits the context.

Due to the leak being so clearly bound to the exceptions being thrown I have the theory that alloca() is failing to free the memory when exceptions are thrown.

Is this at all plausible? It strikes me as a major defect in alloca() if true but when I google alloca() it seems to generally be a problem.

I'd appreciate the insight on any experts.

Comment: Since `alloca()` is not part of the C++ standard I should not think there is any guarantees. Unless you are using some underlying C library you should not be using `malloc()` or `alloca()` but using smart pointers. Smart pointers will provide automatic garbage collection of the object and be exception safe.

Comment: Yeah those are used in many places as well. But there's lots of alloca()s regardless. At the moment I'm just trying to understand what could explain the memory leaks. The way alloca() is explained to me is that it should automagically free all it's memory. Which does seems to work as long as there are no exceptions occurring.

Comment: From the docs on `alloca()`: `The alloca() function is machine- and compiler-dependent.` So I don't think there is anything you could guarantee. But the docs say the space is allocated in the stack frame. Which means that when the function returns it ***should*** be deallocated. **BUT** the destructor will not be called in these situations so if an object used memory management internally that space would not be de-allocated correctly.

Comment: Have you tried  [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) ? BTW,  `alloca` certainly does *not* work like the JVM garbage collector. Read also [the GC handbook](http://gchandbook.org/)

Comment: @MartinYork "if an object used memory management internally that space would not be de-allocated correctly" This could be happening in at least a few cases. So that may be the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch "certainly does not work like the JVM garbage collector. " lol yeah I can't imagine it does but that's how the OG devs are explaining it to me.

Comment: What are OG devs?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Original devs

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch https://www.dictionary.com/e/slang/og/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is likely that the problem is due to a level of indirection.

The literal question is "does `alloca` return memory if an exception is thrown?". And the answer to that is; It returns **only** the memory that was directly allocated. No destructors are run, and any owning pointer inside the `alloca`-allocated memory is leaked.

Comment: That's very likely what could be happening.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ you should not be using the C memory management routines. In modern C++ the smart pointers provide you with fine grained deterministic garbage collection.

Though the space allocated via `alloca()` is probably deallocated with exceptions (because it is usually done by increasing the size of the current stack frame). This is not part of the standard and thus I don't think you can make any guarantees.

**BUT** This also means that any appropriate destructors on the object are never going to be called. Which means that if the object does its own memory management this will not be cleaned up (because the destructor is not run to clean it up).

Though `alloca()` is probably very fast. I think the extra burden it adds for memory management is (in the general case) not worth it; though if you have a special need for extra speed it may be worth it.

Code the looks like this:

```
void func()
{
    MyType* x = (MyType*)alloca(sizeof(MyType));

    passXtoCFunctionThatDoesNotTakeOwnership(x);
}
```

Should be written like this:

```
void func()
{
    std::unique_ptr<MyType> x = std::make_unique<MyType>();

    passXtoCFunctionThatDoesNotTakeOwnership(x.get());
}
```

If you are using it to hold an array of objects.

```
void func()
{
    MyType* x = (MyType*)alloca(sizeof(MyType) * arraySize);

    // STUFF
    x[0].stuff();
}
```

Then it is better to use a std::vector

```
void func()
{
    std::vector<MyType> x;
    x.reserve(arraySize);   // or resize() if that is appropriate

    // STUFF
    x[0].stuff();
}
```

If you are using it for simple objects. Then you should probably just be declaring automatic variables:

```
void func()
{
    MyType* x = (MyType*)alloca(sizeof(MyType));

    x->myData = 5;
}
```

You should just be declaring a variable:

```
void func()
{
    MyType x;

    x.myData = 5;
}
```

Comment: If I could write this whole thing from scratch again I would definitely do it this way. Thanks!

Comment: @kutuzof: Even if not rewriting from scratch, this is still the easier option compared to getting all those `alloca` problems fixed.

Comment: lol, I just want to throw this whole thing in the garbage and rewrite it in java. I think those upfront costs would ultimately save us this constant maintenance.

Comment: I am not at all sure that rewriting in Java will improve maintainability and/or performance. (Java is a legacy language, you could consider also [Go](https://golang.org/),  [Ocaml](http://ocaml.org/),  [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), and even Common Lisp with [SBCL](http://sbcl.org/)...) But it really depends what your application is actually doing

Answer (score 0):

From Linux [man](https://linux.die.net/man/3/alloca)

> ....
>
> Because the space allocated by alloca() is allocated within the stack
>   frame, that space is automatically freed **if the function return** is
>   jumped over by a call to longjmp(3) or siglongjmp(3).
>
> ....
>
> The inlined code often consists of a single instruction adjusting the
>   stack pointer, and does not check for stack overflow. Thus, there is
>   no NULL error return.
>
> .....
>
> **Bugs** There is **no error indication** if the stack frame cannot be
>   extended. (However, after a failed allocation, the program is likely
>   to **receive a SIGSEGV** signal if it attempts to access the unallocated
>   space.) On many systems alloca() cannot be used inside the list of
>   arguments of a function call, because the stack space reserved by
>   alloca() would appear on the stack in the middle of the space for the
>   function arguments.

In this way, exception cannot cause memory leak for memory allocated by alloca in the stack frame. However, this, like any exception, can lead to heap memory leaks since destructors and memory freeing methods placed after alloca will be skipped.

Comment: Ok, yeah that sounds very plausible. This software is also running on Linux so that seems to make sense. Thanks so much!

Comment: This is not actually a good answer, and probably should not have been accepted. As the comments note, the problem here is that `alloca` is a function form in some C runtime libraries. As such, the man page is written with C in mind. That's why it does talk about `longjmp` and ignores `throw`. A good answer should address that interworking.

Comment: @MSalters ok, good point. I would actually describe this software as a mix of C and C++. It was originally a C application that eventually grew into C++. Does that make more sense?

Comment: @kutuzof: I've seen more than a few of those. It's probably a bit of an unintended side-effect of C++ being very compatible with C, but not perfectly. Add non-standard functions like `alloca`, and you get engineering challenges. Manageable, but not easy.

Comment: @MSalters, You're right. I really missed the talk about destructors calls. I think the author hastened with a answer choice.

Comment: @MSalters " you get engineering challenges. Manageable, but not easy." lol, tell me about it. Thanks so much for the advice!

Comment: @DmytroDadyka Thanks to you as well!